# SWT texts not properly aligned in gridlayout

Tags: java, swt

When I added the two Text controls (dUsername and dPassword), they are not properly aligned. Please refer the screen capture attached. 
The two Text controls added next to the combo should be placed under their respective label headings. However, I am not able to find the cause of the improper alignment. it would be of great help if I could get any pointers regarding the same.

```
 public void createControl(Composite Parent) {
            Composite container = new Composite(Parent, SWT.NULL);
            GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
            container.setLayout(layout);
            layout.numColumns = 10;
            layout.verticalSpacing = 20;
            layout.horizontalSpacing = 15;

            GridData gd1 = new GridData(GridData.BEGINNING, GridData.BEGINNING, false, false, 1, 1);
            createLabelSection(container,gd1);
            getARowForEach(container,gd1);
        }
        private void getARowForEach(Composite container, GridData grid) {

            while (some condition) {
                String dString = (String) dIterator.next();
                addControls(dString, container, grid);
            }
        }

        private void addControls(String dvString, Composite container, GridData grid) {
            Button checkBox = setCheckBoxText(container, null);
            String dvLabel = dvString;

            getLabelCaption(container,dvLabel);

            Combo hostCombo = setComboText(container);
            Text dUsername = new Text(container, SWT.NONE);         
            Text dPassword = new Text(container, SWT.PASSWORD);

            }
            public Button setCheckBoxText(Composite container, Label label){
            Button checkBox = new Button(container, SWT.CHECK);
            GridData gd = new GridData(GridData.FILL, GridData.CENTER, true, false, 2, 1);
            checkBox.setLayoutData(gd);
            checkBox.setSelection(true);
            return checkBox;
        }

            public Label getLabelCaption(Composite container, String caption){
            Label label = new Label(container, SWT.NONE);
            GridData grid = new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.TOP, false, false, 1, 1);
            label.setLayoutData(grid);
            label.setText(caption);
            return label;
        }
        public Combo setComboText(Composite container){
            Combo combo = new Combo(container, SWT.READ_ONLY);

            GridData gd = new GridData(GridData.FILL, GridData.CENTER, true, false, 2, 1);
            combo.setLayoutData(gd);
            .
            .     
            combo.select(0);
            return combo;
        }
        private void createLabelSection(Composite container,GridData grid ) {
            addLabel(container, grid, "some details");
            addLabel(container, grid, "some details");
            addLabel(container,  grid, "some details");
            addLabel(container, grid,"username");
            addLabel(container, grid, "password");
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you're trying to simulate a table using controls.

You are complicating yourself trying to align the widgets perfectly. Just make a master container with as many columns as you need (in your screenshot there are 5) and then simply create a method which adds rows to that container.

Run this:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Combo;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;

/**
 * 
 * @author ggrec
 *
 */
public class Tester
{

    // ==================== 3. Static Methods ====================

    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        new Tester();
    }


    // ==================== 4. Constructors ====================

    private Tester()
    {
        final Display display = new Display();
        final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

        createContents(shell);

        shell.pack();
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed())
        {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }


    // ==================== 5. Creators ====================

    private static void createContents(final Composite parent)
    {
        final Composite mainContainer = new Composite(parent, SWT.NULL);
        mainContainer.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, false));
        mainContainer.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

        createHeaderRow(mainContainer);

        createRow(mainContainer);
        createRow(mainContainer);
        createRow(mainContainer);
    }


    /**
     * @param parent Must have a grid layout with 5 columns!
     */
    private static void createHeaderRow(final Composite parent)
    {
        new Label(parent, SWT.NULL); // Filler label

        final Label nameLabel = new Label(parent, SWT.BORDER);
        nameLabel.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.CENTER, SWT.CENTER, true, true));
        nameLabel.setText("Name");

        final Label comboLabel = new Label(parent, SWT.BORDER);
        comboLabel.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.CENTER, SWT.CENTER, true, true));
        comboLabel.setText("Combo");

        final Label usernameLabel = new Label(parent, SWT.BORDER);
        usernameLabel.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.CENTER, SWT.CENTER, true, true));
        usernameLabel.setText("Username");

        final Label passwordLabel = new Label(parent, SWT.BORDER);
        passwordLabel.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.CENTER, SWT.CENTER, true, true));
        passwordLabel.setText("Password");
    }


    /**
     * @param parent Must have a grid layout with 5 columns!
     */
    private static void createRow(final Composite parent/*, final Entity model*/)
    {
        final Button checkbox = new Button(parent, SWT.CHECK);
        checkbox.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.CENTER, SWT.CENTER, true, true));

        final Label nameLabel = new Label(parent, SWT.NULL);
        nameLabel.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.CENTER, SWT.CENTER, true, true));
        nameLabel.setText("FirstName LastName");

        final Combo combo = new Combo(parent, SWT.NULL);
        combo.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.CENTER, SWT.CENTER, true, true));

        final Text usernameWidget = new Text(parent, SWT.NULL);
        usernameWidget.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.CENTER, SWT.CENTER, true, true));

        final Text passwordWidget = new Text(parent, SWT.NULL);
        passwordWidget.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.CENTER, SWT.CENTER, true, true));
    }

}
```

Comment: Text dashUsername = new Text(container, SWT.NONE);
dashUsername.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.BEGINNING, false, false, 2, 1));
  
  Text dashPassword = new Text(container, SWT.PASSWORD);
  dashPassword.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.BEGINNING, false, false, 2, 1));

Comment: I tried with this and found that the Texts are aligned properly with the existing code. Thanks for the help GGrec.